# Como posso extrair um caractere de uma string em PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho esse código em PHP que pega informação de um arquivo texto, essa informação que vem desse arquivo, vem tipo em colunas delimitada por | como pode ver eu fiz um explode no | o resultado veio a coluna inteira pois a informação do arquivo vinha assim:

Exemplo:

```
| campo1   | nivel  | campo3        | campo4     |
| material |   1    | componente    | quantidade |
| material |   2    | componente2   | quantidade |
```

O resultado no explode sai assim: 
Exemplo:

```
0=> material material material... até a ultima linha
mesmo coisa para as outras colunas
1=> 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 ... até a ultima linha do arquivo texto.
No nível 1 ele é pai do 2 e o 2 é pai no 3 e assim sucessivamente.
```

Ou seja, eu preciso pegar essa tabela e jogar no banco de dados assim com a coluna2_pai:

```
| coluna1  | nível |  coluna2_pai  | coluna2      | coluna3 |
| material |   1   |  componente1  | componente1  |  tipo   |
| material |   2   |  componente1  | componente2  |  tipo   |
| material |   3   |  componente2  | componente3  |  tipo   |
| material |   1   | componente1.1 | componente1.1|  tipo   |
| material |   2   | componente1.1 | componente1.2|  tipo   |
```

Explicando o que quero fazer na coluna2_pai vai receber os componentes do nível pai para cada nivel filho. O nivel 1 é o nivel máximo não tem pai o seu filho vai ser sempre o nível 2 abaixo dele.

Exemplo:

```
nivel 
1
2
2
2
1
2
```

Então nesse caso o primeiro nível 1 só vai ser pai dos níveis 2 até o próximo nível 1 a mesma coisa serve para os próximos níveis 1 e do nível 2 para o 3 e assim por diante.

```
$material = fopen("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/material1.txt","r");

//$materiais = file("material1.txt");

while(!feof($material)){

    $linha = fgets($material,1024);

    $valor = explode('|',$linha);

    $nivel = $valor[3];

    $component = $valor[4];

    $array_nivel[$nivel] = $component;

    $nivel_pai = $nivel - 1;

    //$array_nivel[0] = $valor[1];

    //echo $valor[3]."\n";

    echo "Nivel ".$nivel_pai." Pai: ".$array_nivel[$nivel]." Filho: ".$component."\n";
    }
```

A parte no `$nivel_pai = $nivel - 1` eu tentei usar a lógica de pegar o valor do nível por exemplo 2 e subtrair por 1 para pegar o componente no nível anterior no caso nível 2 vai ter o componente do 1.

a string seria a coluna em si no caso da coluna nível eu precisaria fazer um if dos valores do nível 1 2 e 3 só como estão na mesma string estou com problema para fazer essa condição, a condição

```
if($nivel == 1){
   $array_nivel[$nivel_pai] = $component;
}elseif($nivel == 2){
   $array_nivel[$nivel_pai] = $component;
   $nivel_pai = $nivel - 1;
}... e por ia vai

já tentei if($nivel <> 1 || $nivel == 2 ...){
  $array_nivel[$nivel_pai] == $component;
  $nivel_pai =  $nivel - 1;
}
```

não dá certo a ideia é comparar esses níveis, e pegar o componente do nivel 1 e colocar da coluna2_pai do nivel 2 o componente do nivel 2 já vai ser posto na coluna2_pai do nivel 3 e assim por diante so que esses niveis estão intercalados

> nivel
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   2
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   3
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   5
>   3
>   2
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   3
>   2

Comment: Acho que tem umas funções em php que faz isso: scanf

Comment: Ola, acho que já percebi a logica. Não percebi a coluna coluna2_pai dos 1.1 e 1.2. Pode dar mais exemplos da coluna por favor

Comment: O que você quer é uma substring de uma string ?
Posta um exemplo da string e qual o resultado esperado após você obter o que você quer da string

Comment: Não era mais simples meter tudo num array de arrays e depois ias buscar o que precisavas. Assim estás a complicar as coisas sem ser preciso.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer pegar cada linha separada? Se for, você deve antes explodir a quebra de linha .. Se for este o problema, faça assim:

```
<?php

$a = '
| campo1   | nivel  | campo3        | campo4     |
| material |   1    | componente    | quantidade |
| material |   2    | componente2   | quantidade |
';
$a = trim($a); // limpa os espaços em branco

$a = explode("\n", $a);
$i = 0;
foreach($a as $v) {
    $v = trim($v);
    if(!empty($v)) {
        $b = explode("|", $v);
        foreach($b as $nv) {
            $nv = trim($nv);
            if(!empty($nv)) {
                // exit(var_dump($nv));
                $dados[$i][] = $nv;
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

E o resultado restante na variável **$dados** é a array abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => campo1
            [1] => nivel
            [2] => campo3
            [3] => campo4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => material
            [1] => 1
            [2] => componente
            [3] => quantidade
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => material
            [1] => 2
            [2] => componente2
            [3] => quantidade
        )

)
```

Se for esta a sua dúvida, espero ter ajudado. Abs.

Comment: Acho que não entendeu, o autor foi bem claro, ele quer separar por níveis. Espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva pra melhorar a sua resposta.